# Would SQL in a cluster failover when transaction log for database is full?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, storage

I have a Microsoft SQL Cluster with one instance. If one of the databases is full, would SQL in a cluster failover when transaction log for database is full?

If it depends on the reason the transaction log is full please refer to following::

1. due to 'log_backup'
2. due to 'availability replica'
3. active_transaction
4. 'replication'
5. 'CHECKPOINT"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it shouldn't because that is not a server level event that the cluster would be aware of when it happens.

I seem to recall coming across an article that referenced specific events that could cause a failover but can't find it right now.

Comment: In addition, a cluster uses shared storage, so how would a failover help?

Comment: @Aaron it might help because failover causes SQL Server to restart.

Comment: @shanky but the database files haven't moved - they're still the same size and they're still on the same full disks. Maybe that would help if tempdb was part of the problem and everything was all on one volume, but even in that hopefully unlikely scenario, that's a very temporary "fix."

Comment: @Aaron I was saying that when failover happens and if problem is due to transaction log full, then in that case tempdb is cleared and this might actually solve the issue when SQL Server comes online. Of course agree with you this is not a solution.

Comment: @Shanky if it's the tempdb transaction log, and that's the only problem, maybe. The OP didn't say it was tempdb. Failover won't help a scenario where any other database's transaction log was full.